# Jquery - Select td value for all the tr with a class

Tags: jquery

I have a table

```
<table>
       <tr class="PO1"></tr>
       <tr class="PO2"></tr>
       <tr class="PO3"></tr>
</table>
```

How can I loop through all tr with class `"PO1"` and get the value of each `'td'` value?

```
$("table#id tr .PO1").each(function(i)
{
    // how to get the td values??
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var values = $('table tr.PO1 td').map(function(_, td) {
    return $(td).text();
}).get();
```

This would just create an array with the text contents from each `td`. Probably a better idea to use a map/object instead:

```
var values = $('table tr.PO1 td').map(function(index, td) {
    var ret = { };

    ret[ index ] = $(td).text();
    return ret;
}).get();
```

Comment: @Bhaskar: the map would even be more expresive if those `td` nodes have unique classes/ids/attribues to set as key. If not, the index is probably the only way to identify.

Comment: @wewals: not exactly. Just mapping the values gives you no idea afterwards where the value within the array came from. By pushing objects into the mapped array, you can provide additional information per value.

Comment: The map that's created is no more informational. The arrays from the first bit of code are indexed, The objects created in the second bit of code are indexed. It's just another layer of nesting. I see what you're getting at though with the fact that you could, potentially, store something of value in the key. In this case though, the key is just what would have been the key in the array of the previous bit of code.

Comment: Hi,

If I want to put the all the td values into an object, I mean all the values in the different tr should go into seperate objects.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: $("#tblPurchaseOrders tr.PO1").map(function(index, tr) {

                var lines = $(tr + " td").map(function(ind, td) {

                    var ret = {};

                    ret[ind] = $(td).text();
                    return ret;

                }).get();

            });

Comment: @wewals: again, just mapping the values into an array is non-informative. Especially when the OP just grabs `tds` with a classname, the original index is lost.

Comment: Putting the values into an array is just as informative as pulling it into an object inside an array. In the array example, the array index is the index that the node was found by the selector (think eq(index)). In the object within an array, the key in the object is the index that the node was found by the selector. No more or less information either way. No information is lost.

Comment: @wewals: `the array index is the index that the node was found` -> not it's of course not! He does not query all tds, but only specific ones (by classname). Why would you expect that this has still the correct order afterwards ?

Comment: jQuery selectors are stored in DOM order. Both of your examples have the same amount of useful information, one just takes more time and memory. I don't know how else to explain it. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The space before the .P01 is what's breaking your current code.

```
$("tr.PO1 td").each(function(i){
    $(this).text()
});
```

Comment: LOL, that's because it's PO1 not P01. o vs zero(0). I've updated the answer code.

Answer (score 1):

notice : I removed a space before .PO1 because your tr has class P01

```
$("table#id tr.PO1").each(function(i)
{
    $(this).find("td").innerHTMl() //for example
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table#id tr.PO1").each(function(i)
{
    i.children('td').each(function(tdEL) {
        // tdEl.val();
    });
});
```

Notice the space I removed between tr and .PO1. In you case it will try to find each tr with an child having the class .PO1.